# sending reply to jms queue in synapse

Tags: oracle, jms, apache-synapse

I have Synapse configuration to read a message from an Oracle JMS queue, invoke web service and capture the response in the log. The configuration is based on [ws02 with oracle](http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2011/11/configuring-wso2-esb-with-oracle-as-messaging-media/)

I've tried to extend the configuration to capture the response in another Oracle quueue but I'm getting an error as below. It seems like, despite indicating the reply destination type as "queue", he's still trying to create a topic session instead of a queue session.

```
2014-12-15 14:13:21,728 [-] [HttpClientWorker-1] ERROR JMSSender Unable to create a JMSMessageSender for : org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSOutTransportInfo@42bed00f oracle.jms.AQjmsException: JMS-107: Operation not allowed on Connection
at oracle.jms.AQjmsError.throwEx(AQjmsError.java:334)
at oracle.jms.AQjmsConnection.createTopicSession(AQjmsConnection.java:728)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSOutTransportInfo.createJMSSender(JMSOutTransportInfo.java:365)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.sendMessage(JMSSender.java:121)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:119)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
```

Configuration:

```
<definitions xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
 <proxy name="StockQuoteProxy" transports="https http jms" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
  <target>
   <endpoint>
     <address uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService" />
   </endpoint>
    <inSequence>
     <log level="full" />
     <enrich>
      <source type="body" clone="true" />
      <target type="property" property="jms_body_text" />
     </enrich>
     <property name="jms_body_text" expression="get-property('jms_body_text')" scope="default" />
      <xslt key="jmsMsgToSoapMsg_xslt">
        <property name="jms_text" expression="get-property('jms_body_text')" />
      </xslt>
      <log level="full">
        <property name="After transformation" value="************" />
      </log>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
     <log level="full">
      <property name="OUT SEQUENCE" value="************" />
     </log>
     <send/>
    </outSequence>
  </target>

  <publishWSDL uri="file:repository/conf/sample/resources/proxy/sample_proxy_1.wsdl"/>

   <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
    <rules>
     <jmsProperty>ContentType</jmsProperty>
     <default>text/plain</default>
    </rules>
  </parameter>

  <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">cn=tro_Q_JMS1,cn=OracleDBQueues,cn=ORCL,cn=OracleContext,ou=Services, o=sgi,c=us</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.jms.ReplyDestinationType">queue</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.jms.ReplyDestination">cn=tro_Q_JMS2,cn=OracleDBQueues,cn=ORCL,cn=OracleContext,ou=Services, o=sgi,c=us</parameter>

 </proxy>

 <localEntry key="jmsMsgToSoapMsg_xslt" src="file:jmsMsgToSoapMsg.xslt" />

 <sequence name="fault">
  <log level="full">
    <property name="MESSAGE" value="Executing default &quot;fault&quot; sequence" />
    <property name="ERROR_CODE" expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')" />
    <property name="ERROR_MESSAGE" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')" />
  </log>
  <drop/>
 </sequence>

 <sequence name="main">
  <log/>
  <drop/>
 </sequence>
</definitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem. It looks like Oracle JMS is not compatible with Axis2 jms transport library.

```
JMSOutTransportInfo(JMSConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory, Destination dest,
        String contentTypeProperty) {
    this.jmsConnectionFactory = jmsConnectionFactory;
    this.destination = dest;
    destinationType = dest instanceof Topic ? JMSConstants.DESTINATION_TYPE_TOPIC
                                            : JMSConstants.DESTINATION_TYPE_QUEUE;
    this.contentTypeProperty = contentTypeProperty;
}
```

In order to determine, whether the destination is a topic or a queue axis2 jms first checks to see if the destination implements the Topic interface. The problem is, the Oracle class is the same for both Topic and Queue, AQjmsDestination which implements both the Topic and the Queue interface.